# jqueryMobile panel theme not working

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I cannot figure out for the life of my why this jquery mobile panel won't render with the same look and feel of the jquery mobile theme used in the application.

The panel is loading on the same page as the rest of my jquery mobile page so the jquery mobile css files and jquery js files are all referenced and working on other parts of the page.

What am I missing within my layout?

thanks

```
 <div data-role="page" id="map_page">
        <div data-role="panel" id="transitLayersPage" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Routes</h1>
            </div>        
            <div data-role="controlgroup">
                <div id="checkboxes">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="transitRoutesLayerKML0" onclick="toggleLayer(0)" />
                    <label>Routes 1</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="transitRoutesLayerKML1" onclick="toggleLayer(1)" />
                    <label>Routes 2</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="transitRoutesLayerKML0" onclick="toggleLayer(2)" />
                    <label>Routes 3</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="transitRoutesLayerKML1" onclick="toggleLayer(3)" />
                    <label>Routes 4</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="transitRoutesLayerKML0" onclick="toggleLayer(4)" />
                    <label>Routes 5</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="transitRoutesLayerKML1" onclick="toggleLayer(5)" />
                    <label>Routes 6a</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="transitRoutesLayerKML0" onclick="toggleLayer(6)" />
                    <label>Routes 6b</label>
                </div>
                <a href="#my-header" data-role="button" data-rel="close">Close panel</a>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `for` attribute to `label`. Moreover, you should not use duplicate `id` for `checkbox`, each `checkbox` must have a unique `id`.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">
<label for="foo">bar</label>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9sMD8/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I didn't know about the 'for =' thing.  That's good to know.  As for the ID's that was just a typo, but it's all straightened out now and working.  Cheers!